# Simulating a large filesystem to test test a large memory map in Windows (>5tb)

Tags: windows, filesystems, ntfs, virtual-memory

Is there a way to simulate a large filesystem that is over 5tb in size when I only have a 1tb disk available to me?

Trying to stress test an application (specifically need to memory map 5tb worth of files)

I know that Xen can oversubscribe disk in linux, but I'm trying to simulate this in windows.

Comment: you could create 5 different shares on that volume and mount them all with different drive letters... this would look like having 5 different 1 TB-volumes... then you can memory map them all...

Comment: Can you clarify some more on what is it you need to test? If you want to just test mmap(5TB), why not create an anonymous object and map it? I.e. why do you need a backing FS worth 5TB? If you want to test IO to such an object, you can create a 1TB file object and keep mapping the same 1TB file at different mmap offsets. More detail might help....

Comment: Yes, you can create a virtual file system of any size (eg. using our Callback File System) and have 5Tb large virtual disk when you don't have so much real space.

Answer (score 0):

With this small piece of software you can create huge files (10TB maximum). No mather what size you choose, it will only take up 4KB from your disk memory.

http://www.shockingsoft.com/HugeFakeFile.html

http://www.technixupdate.com/create-huge-fake-file-10-tb-maximum-with-huge-fake-file-creator/

Similar to this, there are a lots of utilities available. Gooogle for more. Hope this helps.

Comment: These are called [sparse files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file).